# Get the result of translation sended to Google via URL with CURL

Tags: curl, translation, google-translate

Since Google translation services are now paid, I was thinking to send the string to translate via URL and get the translation result but I don't know how to...

**This is the URL I was thinking to send:**

```
$url = 'https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=sl=en&tl=es&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q='.urlencode($description_2_translate).'';
```

The translation result is outputed in a div with a specific indentifier `dir="ltr"`. The echo result should be the text inside that div.

**Example:**

1 - send url with string to translate

2 - get the result inside div `<div dir="ltr" class="t0">the translated text</div>`